# How do nested for loops execute?

Tags: java

I know how a single for loop works. What i don't fully understand is how a nested for loop executes the outer and inner loops. (in Java using netbeans)

1. Does the outer loop run until the condition is met and then go to the inner loop?

OR

2. Does the outer loop and inner loop execute in tandem to each other?

Please explain to me in the most simplest way possible on how a nested loop works.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
   for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++) {
     for (int col = 0; col <= row; col++) {
       System.out.print("*");
     }
     System.out.print("\n");

   }
   System.out.println();
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what kind of questions can be asked here and how to ask them.

Comment: Option 3. For each iteration of the outer loop, the inner loop executes in its entirety.

Comment: better follow atleast one java book

Comment: i downvote because 'This question does not show any research effort' is a valid reason to do so...

Answer (score 1):

The `outer loop` will start execution right away. As soon as the code inside the `outer loop` reaches your `inner loop`, your `inner loop` will start executing in its entirety. Once your `inner loop` is done, your `outer loop` will continue.

Repeat for every iteration of the `outer loop`.

In your example the output will be:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

I do question why you didn't just try it yourself, though...

Comment: Wouldn't the output be repeated 5 times?

Comment: i did try it myself i just didnt understand it fully.

Comment: @TomHart No, because the `inner loop` only runs while `col <= row`

Comment: @ManIkWeet my bad, I misinterpreted what the code actually did :p

Answer (score 1):

@khelwood has it right, the inner loop runs completely for each iteration of the outer loop.

Given your code the output is:

*

**

***

****

*****

This is because on the first iteration of the outer loop 'row' is set to 0 so the inner loop only has one iteration (0 <= 0).

On the second iteration of the outer loop 'row' is set to 1 so the inner loop has two iterations (0, 1 <= 1).

On the third iteration of the outer loop 'row' is set to 2 so the inner loop has three iterations (0, 1, 2 <= 2).

On the forth iteration of the outer loop 'row' is set to 3 so the inner loop has four iterations (0, 1, 2, 3 <= 3).

On the fifth iteration of the outer loop 'row' is set to 4 so the inner loop has five iterations (0, 1, 2, 3, 4 <= 4).

Comment: this was very helpful

Comment: so when (0 <= 0) is run, a col value is printed but because it is 0 the compiler doesnt display it is it like that?

Comment: No when 0 <= 0 (zero is less than or equal to zero) is checked it evaluates to true. Because it evaluates to true the code in the loop is executed (System.out.print("*");) and a star is outputted to the console.  The outer loop has 5 iterations which means the inner loop will run 5 times, the first time the inner loop runs a * will be printed the second time it runs ** will be printed and so on until the fifth time it runs and ***** will be printed. What are you seeing outputted to the console? Are you still asking in regards to your original code, or do you have code that is not working?